# Limit query on a Magento non eav table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a custom table in my database with approximately 900 000 rows. I am running this query:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("similar/flipkart")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('title', array('like' => '%'.$query.'%')) ->setCurPage(1)
                ->setPageSize(4);
```

This query takes more than 12 seconds to return result. However when I run limit query on mysql table, I get result instantaneously. How do I speed up my process. When  logged the query, I got this:

```
`SELECT main_table.* FROM flipkart_furn AS main_table WHERE (title LIKE '%chai%')`
```

So basically limit did not append to it. How do i make limit gets appended to it

Comment: Have you indexed the title column?

Comment: The reason I ask is that LIMIT, unless you actually want to limit your results, is just a cheap work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran direct SQL query from like this way (Although not a good answer but just a workaround):

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
    */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    /**
     * Retrieve our table name
    */
    $table = $resource->getTableName('similar/flipkart');

    /**
     * Set the product ID
    */
    //$productId = 44;

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE title like "%'.$query1.'%" LIMIT 4';

    /**
     * Execute the query and store the result in $sku
     */
    $products = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    //$sku = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);


    /* $products = Mage::getModel("similar/flipkart")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('title', array('like' => '%'.$query.'%')) ->setCurPage(1)
                ->setPageSize(4);
    Mage::log((string)$products->getSelect(),null,"mylogfile1.log",true);*/
    return $products;
```

I ran this from my magento model class directly. I got the result in no time

Comment: Please mark your post as answer, as this question shows still as open. Thanks!

Comment: i can mark my answer as accepted only after 2 days,i.e., tomorrow. You are free to upvote it btw!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You can't, really!
The long answer: You are dealing with Magento with a huge EAV model in the background. Depending on the item count in your database it just needs time to fetch the data, very likely that Magento `join` some tables which makes this even longer.

One way could be to *not* use `like` (fuzzy) but to use `=` (sharp).

```
$products = Mage::getModel("similar/flipkart")
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('title', $query)
                ->setCurPage(1)
                ->setPageSize(4);
```

`like` searches are really performance expensive.

If you can't go for `=` instead of `like` you maybe ramp up your server and optimize your database. Here is a [superb article](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/) "Magento on Steroids" on how to improve database performance.

Also I would suggest a [database maintenance](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-perform-magento-database-maintenance.html) as described in the article by Nexcess.

Limit just reduce the amount of results you get back - normally that also makes are query faster! Furthermore a query run directly on the server (with mysql workbench) is always faster that a query that need to be processed through an ORM, and Magento uses its own ORM.

Comment: The table is NON EAV (already added that in question header). Again if run the limit query directly in mysql workbench, I get result within a fraction of a second. then why is the discrepancy

Comment: This is the query which gets executed:   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `flipkart_furn` AS `main_table` WHERE (title LIKE '%chai%') . So basically there is no limit appended to it. So obviously its gonna take time. limit should be appended to get faster results

Comment: Limit just reduce the amount of results you get back - normally that also makes are query faster! Furthermore a query run directly on the server (with mysql workbench) is always faster that a query that need to be processed through an ORM, and Magento uses its own ORM.

Comment: So no way apart from database optimization. OK

Comment: Sorry no. If you'd like, you can accept my post as answer.

Comment: ran a direct sql query from magento model and got the result. I know  I am breaking the ORM thing, but i guess that's the only way. posted that as an answer

Comment: Well, running raw SQL queries are always faster that the ORM. But the ORM takes f. ex. care of SQL injection, your direct query doesn't. Anyway...